# Problem with Trying to install dual boot windows/ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, usb-drive

As the title states, tried installing ubuntu with windows 10 already installed. It was working but in the background. I accidentally removed the flash drive while installing and my computer crashed. So i started the process again but now its not giving me the option of installing as a dual boot, it wants me to format disk and install ubuntu alone. How do i fix this? Windows still works and I want to keep it on the system. How do i get rid of the old partitions to restart the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From windows or live media you can identify the partition(s) used for Ubuntu.

Then you can start then installer and either:

1. select "Something else" and manually map the partition(s) to the mountpoint(s).

or

2. delete them so you have free space on the disk for new installation. Then install "Alongside Windows".

Be absolutely sure that it is the right partition(s) you choose to overwrite & delete. A backup of important windows data might be a good thing to have is you by accident destroys Windows.

Eventually you could update the question with the output of `sudo blkid` if you want advise onwht partition(s) to overwrite or delete.

Comment: How do I find/identify the partitions?